# How to react to changes in SimpleForm Inputs?

Tags: redux-form, admin-on-rest

I'm making a custom input component that needs to change when other input values are changed in the form.

```
<ReferenceInput source="foo">
  <SelectInput />
</ReferenceInput>
<NumberInput onChange={(e, newValue) => {this.setState({ newValue })} />
<CustomInput numberValue={this.state.newValue} />
```

When `NumberInput` changes, I can pass `CustomInput` the new value. But `ReferenceInput / SelectInput` doesn't have an `onChange`. How do I get the new value of `SelectInput` to the `CustomInput`? (Note that inside `CustomInput`, `props.record.foo` doesn't update when `ReferenceInput` changes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out aor dependent input

https://github.com/marmelab/aor-dependent-input

Comment: Thanks, when I wrap `CustomInput` in `<DependentInput resolve={() => true}>`, `CustomInput` gets `this.props.dependsOnValue.foo`, which updates on changes.